# Android: Convert a normal menu to slider menu? (With minimal coding)

Tags: java, android, menu, slider

I have an app with a normal menu i.e. the common old menu that shows up at the bottom of the screen when the menu button is pressed. But it is a problem in some phones where there is no hard menu button.

I want to switch to slider menu with a menu icon on top. Is there an easy way to do this (I mean a way where code change would be minimum) retaining the existing functionality? Or will i have to go about coding the slider menu from scratch?

Any example code of a similar situation would really help.

Comment: pls take a look at this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: @ASP thanks, but I'm trying to figure out a solution where I can avoid doing the entire coding. I rephrased the question to be more clear about the kind of info i'm looking for. But thanks for the link. If there is no possible way to do what I'm hoping to do, the given link would definitely prove helpful.

Comment: I guess, you don't need to write the entire code from scratch. From the above link, you can understand how to use Navigation Drawer. Then , you can implement it in your project as per your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an app with a normal menu i.e. the common old menu that shows up at the bottom of the screen when the menu button is pressed

Normally, that "menu" will appear as [the overflow](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) on devices with an action bar that either:

- do not have a MENU button, or
- run Android 4.4+

> But it is a problem in some phones where there is no hard menu button.

Make sure that your app has an action bar.

> I want to switch to slider menu with a menu icon on top

The options menu/action-bar-with-overflow is unrelated to the "slider menu". They serve different roles. Please read [the design guidelines for a navigation drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) (a.k.a., "slider menu").

> Is there an easy way to do this (I mean a way where code change would be minimum) retaining the existing functionality?

No, because they are not related.

Comment: Thanks! This looks close to what I wanted. From the above I guess that slider is not an option without major code addition or change. Just to confirm when I add the action bar the menu automatically shows as overflow right? Any extra coding needed in this case except for that required to add an action bar?

Comment: Will it retain the icons too?

Comment: @Viral: "Just to confirm when I add the action bar the menu automatically shows as overflow right?" -- yes. "Any extra coding needed in this case except for that required to add an action bar?" -- no. "Will it retain the icons too?" -- within the normal styling of the action bar. Items in the overflow do not use icons. Items in the action bar itself (e.g., `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`) will use the icon alone by default.